# ReactJS Dynamic input states

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, state

I need to add an "Add input" button which adds a `<div>` with some inputs. That works fine but if I remove some element (for example the first one) it will deletes the last one no matter what.

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399688/adding-dynamic-states-in-reactjs) but I can't figure out how to bring it to my scenario.

I have created [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-visvesvaraya-4q2xh?file=/src/App.js) to see "the bigger picture".

The main idea is whenever you click over "Add input" it adds that `div` to `addedInputs` state array:

```js
function addInputElement(inputId) {
    const input = inputs[inputId];
    input.id = inputId;
    setAddedInputs([...addedInputs, input]);
    setSelectedValue("default");
    setAddInput(false);
}
```

When you write in any input of it, it adds it also to an object `inputValue` with the same index number as `addedInputs` array.

```js
function changeInputValue(element, index, value) {
    const iv = inputValue;
    if (iv[index]) {
      Object.assign(iv[index], { [element]: value });
    } else {
      Object.assign(iv, { [index]: { [element]: value } });
    }
    setInputValue(iv);
}
```

But when I remove the input from `addedInputs` and it attempts to delete the content from `inputValue` it deletes the right `addedInputs` element but does not deletes the right `inputValue` element:

```js
function removeInputElement(index) {
    const filteredInputs = addedInputs.filter((input, i) => i !== index);
    setAddedInputs(filteredInputs);
    if (inputValue[index] !== undefined) {
      const ivs = inputValue;
      delete ivs[index];
      setInputValue(ivs);
    }
}
```

Well, I am not sure if that is right approach for creating dynamic inputs states but, anyway my "error" here is that I am doing something wrong when removing an input value from `inputValues`. So, what am I doing wrong?

In case you want the entire code here:

```js
import React from "react";

const inputs = {
  "123": { name: "Simple text input", type: "text" },
  "456": { name: "Simple number input", type: "number" }
};

export default function App() {
  const [addedInputs, setAddedInputs] = React.useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState({});
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState("default");
  const [addInput, setAddInput] = React.useState(false);

  function addInputElement(inputId) {
    const input = inputs[inputId];
    input.id = inputId;
    setAddedInputs([...addedInputs, input]);
    setSelectedValue("default");
    setAddInput(false);
  }

  function removeInputElement(index) {
    const filteredInputs = addedInputs.filter((input, i) => i !== index);
    setAddedInputs(filteredInputs);
    if (inputValue[index] !== undefined) {
      const ivs = inputValue;
      delete ivs[index];
      setInputValue(ivs);
    }
  }

  function changeInputValue(element, index, value) {
    const iv = inputValue;
    if (iv[index]) {
      Object.assign(iv[index], { [element]: value });
    } else {
      Object.assign(iv, { [index]: { [element]: value } });
    }
    setInputValue(iv);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {addedInputs.map((input, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h5>{input.name}</h5>
          <input
            placeholder="Title"
            type="text"
            value={
              inputValue[index] &&
              inputValue[index][input.id] &&
              inputValue[index][input.id].title
            }
            onChange={(e) => {
              changeInputValue("title", index, e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <input
            placeholder="Description"
            type="text"
            value={
              inputValue[index] &&
              inputValue[index][input.id] &&
              inputValue[index][input.id].title
            }
            onChange={(e) => {
              changeInputValue("description", index, e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          &nbsp;
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              removeInputElement(index);
            }}
          >
            X
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
      {addInput && (
        <select
          defaultValue={selectedValue}
          onChange={(e) => {
            addInputElement(e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          <option disabled value="default">
            Select an option
          </option>
          {Object.keys(inputs).map((key, index) => {
            const input = inputs[key];
            return (
              <option key={index} value={key}>
                {input.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      )}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setAddInput(true);
        }}
      >
        Add input
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** Overall Problems **

1. Your code is a bit more complex than it has to be, which is the first cause of your bug(s).
   1a. You have the `addedInputs` state variable, which tracks information about the inputs, but
   1b. ...you also have the `inputValue` variable, which tracks multiple input values.
2. Your naming conventions (the way that you decide *what* to call your variables & keys) could use some work. Here are two examples, although there are probably more.
   2a. Your `inputs` variable. Inputs don't necessarily have names, titles & descriptions. You should name this variable after the actual, real-world object you are trying to model.
   2b. Your `inputValue` variable. As I said above, this variable shouldn't exist, but if you want it to, please put an `s` at the end, because it does not track a *single value*, as the name would suggest, but rather all the values across your inputs.

**Solution (to your immediate problem)**
Scrap the `inputValue` variable, and store each "input"'s value on that input.

Here's a working example in which I scrap the inputValue variable, making things much easier:

```js
import React from "react";

const inputs = {
  "123": { name: "Simple text input", type: "text" },
  "456": { name: "Simple number input", type: "number" }
};

export default function App() {
  const [addedInputs, setAddedInputs] = React.useState([]);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState("default");
  const [addInput, setAddInput] = React.useState(false);

  function addInputElement(inputId) {
    const input = inputs[inputId];
    input.id = inputId;
    input.title = input.title || "A Default Title";
    setAddedInputs([...addedInputs, input]);
    setSelectedValue("default");
    setAddInput(false);
  }

  function removeInputElement(index) {
    const filteredInputs = addedInputs.filter((input, i) => i !== index);
    setAddedInputs(filteredInputs);
  }

  function changeInputValue(key, index, value) {
    const newAddedInput = { ...addedInputs[index], [key]: value };
    const newAddedInputs = [...addedInputs];
    newAddedInputs[index] = newAddedInput;
    setAddedInputs(newAddedInputs);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {addedInputs.map((input, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h5>{input.name}</h5>
          <input
            placeholder="Title"
            type="text"
            value={addedInputs[index] && addedInputs[index].title}
            onChange={(e) => {
              changeInputValue("title", index, e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <input
            placeholder="Description"
            type="text"
            value={addedInputs[index] && addedInputs[index].description}
            onChange={(e) => {
              changeInputValue("description", index, e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          &nbsp;
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              removeInputElement(index);
            }}
          >
            X
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
      {addInput && (
        <select
          defaultValue={selectedValue}
          onChange={(e) => {
            addInputElement(e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          <option disabled value="default">
            Select an option
          </option>
          {Object.keys(inputs).map((key, index) => {
            const input = inputs[key];
            return (
              <option key={index} value={key}>
                {input.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      )}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setAddInput(true);
        }}
      >
        Add input
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```